# How to exclude the VENV in Docker PUSH

Tags: python-3.x, docker, dockerfile

I have a basic Python script that I would like to containerize. As part of the script, I am to `pip install az.cli` which is almost 500 mb in size. Locally, it works all right. When I `docker build` it, and `docker run` it, it works just as how it's supposed to work. The issue is when I want to `docker push` it (to `dockerhub` for now).

It's packaging the entire project with the venv, that's ~550 mb. I'd like to avoid that, if possible. I added the venv directory in the `.dockerignore` file, but that doesn't seem to help. I know it's pushing the whole container to dockerhub, so I guess, esentially, is there a way to build/run the docker application without the essence `az.cli` baked in?

FYI: I am new to Docker, so what I am asking may not make sense.

Comment: Please, provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Your Dockerfile should generally `RUN pip install -r requirements.txt` or `RUN pipenv install --deploy --system`, without using a virtual environment; the Docker image itself provides an isolated Python installation.  There are some tricks if you have build-time dependencies, but fundamentally this will need to install the library and its run-time dependencies; if it's really half a gigabyte on its own then your image will always be that big.